# Why does Amazon RDS limits SQL Server databases to 30?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I understand is part of the Amazon RDS limits, but haven't found a comprehensive reason for it. Can anybody think of one? Maybe Microsoft licensing?

[Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html) is AWS documentation on the issue:

> You can create up to 30 databases on each of your DB instances running Microsoft SQL Server. The Microsoft system databases, such as master and model, don't count toward this limit.

Comment: Amm... I think it may be developers thinking: `No one will use so much databases, let it be 30`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RDS database limit exists to support Multi-AZ, which uses Microsoft SQL Server Mirroring.  When Microsoft first introduced Mirroring they recommended a maximum of 10 mirrored databases per server (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366349(SQL.90).aspx).  While the number of databases that can be mirrored has grown over time with increased numbers of faster processors and larger memories, there are still practical limits.  Those limits are not just around performance and resource utilization, but extend to areas such as backup strategies. RDS took those into account in limiting the number of databases per instance to 30.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. We fire up many databases over a RDS managed SQL Server instance, but it presents as a limitation for considering a SQL Server managed by RDS scenario, for development for example. It is making us "manage" a managed database service.